# How can i get this to run as soon as the page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want this fancyBox to run as soon as the page has loaded instead of having to click on a image.

In the javascript code i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

                type : 'image',
                maxWidth    : 800,
                padding     : 0,
                fitToView   : true,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height  : '70%',
                autoSize    : true,
                closeClick  : false,
                nextEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                mousewheel : true

        });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Like the others said, you can just trigger the click event for your fancybox selector. All you'd have to do is add `.click();` after the closing `)` of the fancybox function call. `$(".fancybox").fancybox({}).click();`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that .fancybox is the image in question, `$(".fancybox").click()` at the end of your `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/blog):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#your_selector").trigger('click');
});
```

Where `your_selector` has a fancybox attached to it, so in your case this would be `.fancybox`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a dirty hack

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

                type : 'image',
                maxWidth    : 800,
                padding     : 0,
                fitToView   : true,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height  : '70%',
                autoSize    : true,
                closeClick  : false,
                nextEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                mousewheel : true

        });
 $(".fancybox").click();
        });
```

it seems like its the [**documented way**](http://fancybox.net/blog)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_selector").trigger('click');
});
```